# Subtheme (bootstrap) migrate Drupal 7 to 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, bootstrap-4, drupal-8

I can not find any documentation to migrate my drupal 7 subtheme to drupal 8. I migrate, but everytime I migrate, my UI is broken and if I try installing bootstrap on Drupal 8 I get:

`Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException: Configuration objects (bootstrap.settings) provided by bootstrap already exist in active configuration in Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException::create() (line 65 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/PreExistingConfigException.php).`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove configuration object before reinstalling Bootstrap

This configuration object, i.e. bootstrap.settings probably exists because it has remained over from last time you installed bootstrap. So you have to delete this configuration object before you again install bootstrap. 
If you have drush version 8, try this command: 
 
`drush config-delete bootstrap.settings`

Then try reinstalling bootstrap. 
This should definitely work.